# Random variable is $\xi(\omega)=\omega^{\alpha}, \alpha<0.$ Find distribution function $F(t)=P(w^\alpha < t)$: answer not matching the one in textbook

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Sample space $\Omega=[0,1].$ Our random variable is $\xi(\omega)=\omega^{\alpha}, \alpha<0.$ (Takes a point $\omega \in [0,1],$ returns value $\omega^{\alpha}$).  Find distribution function $F(t)=P(w^\alpha < t).$

My answer does not match the answer in the textbook.

[image: random variable graph]

From the graph it's clear that, for $t \in (-\infty, 1], \ F(t) = P(\omega^\alpha <t) = 0$ (horizontal lines do not cross the graph).

To compute $F(t)$ for $t>1$, we need to divide $c_1+c_2$ by the area of the subgraph of $\omega^\alpha$, from which the area of the unit square has been subtracted.

$c_1 = t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}(t-1) = t^{\frac{1+\alpha}{\alpha}} - t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ = area of the blue rectangle,

$$
c_2=-1\cdot(1-t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}) + \int_{t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}^1 \omega^{\alpha} d \omega
= -1 + t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} + \frac{1}{1+\alpha} \omega^{1+\alpha} \bigg|_{t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}^{1} = -1 + t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} + \frac{1}{1+\alpha} - \frac{1}{1+\alpha}t^{\frac{1+\alpha}{\alpha}}.
$$

$$
c_1 + c_2 = - \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha} + t^{\frac{1+\alpha}{\alpha}} \left( \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha} \right).
$$

The area of the whole subgraph minus the unit square:

$$
-1 + \int_0^1 \omega^{\alpha} d \omega = -1 + \frac{1}{1+\alpha} \omega^{1+\alpha} \bigg|_{0}^{1} = - \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}.
$$

My answer is:
$$
F(t) = -(c_1 + c_2) \frac{1+\alpha}{\alpha} = 1 - t^{\frac{1+\alpha}{\alpha}},
$$

but the textbook answer for $t>1$ is $1-t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}.$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't define the measure $P$ on $\Omega.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[21111](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oahbw.jpg)

Смотри, $F_\xi(t)=P(\xi < t) = P(\omega : \xi(\omega) < t).$ Тебе нужно найти вероятность попадания $\omega$ в интервал такой, что $\xi(\omega) < t$. Глядя на рисунок понятно, что это  $[t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}},1].$ Длина этого отрезка $ 1-t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$. Вот ты и получил функцию распределения для $t > 1.$

*Translated to English with the help of https://translate.google.com:*

Look, $F_\xi(t)=P(\xi < t) = P(\omega : \xi(\omega) < t).$ You need to find the probability of $\omega$ falling into the interval such that $\xi(\omega) < t$. Looking at the figure, it is clear that this is $[t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}},1].$ The length of this segment is $ 1-t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$. So you got the distribution function for $t > 1.$

Comment: Please translate your answer into english.

Comment: See, $F_\xi(t) = P(\xi < t) = P(\omega : \xi(\omega) < t).$
 You need to find the probability of $\omega$
 into the interval such that $\xi < t.$ Looking at the figure it is clear that this is[ $t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$,1].
 The length of this interval is 1-$t^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$
. Here you have the distribution function for $t > 1.$

Comment: Thank you, but better edit your answer than put the translation in comment.

Comment: кто бы ты ни был/а, таинственный соучащийся / таинственная соучащаяся, ты меня напугал/а до смерти: ты зачем меня нашёл или нашла?!. 
за ответ — сердечное спасибо, хотя я уже и сам додумался.